# How can I remove the first word of each line of a program's output?

Tags: bash, shell

This is output of speedtest-cli. I just need the specific values without the `Download:` and `Upload:` headers.

How can I do this?

```
Download: 8.34 Mbit/s
Upload: 0.69 Mbit/s
```

Comment: `Speedtest-cli | sed -nE '/Download|Upload/s/^.*: //p'`  and you're welcome :-)

Comment: Answers don't belong in questions. Use the "Add an Answer" button to add your answer _as an answer_ -- that way you can accept it to mark the question solved, which just editing the solution in doesn't do. (Also, adding the answer to the question means folks can't upvote/downvote/comment on the answer separately from the question).

Answer (score 0):

You can print only 2nd "word" using awk

```
awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: I Try It But It's Not Working 
This Link Is The Output From Speedtest-cli 
https://termbin.com/gstz

I need such an output :

```8.34 Mbit/s```
```0.69 Mbit/s```